# Autogenerate unit tests for legacy javascript code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Is there a tool that can auto-generate unit tests for javascript/jquery code?

We use karma/jasmine for our new code and all is finе there. For the legacy code we are writing unit tests (and refactoring it of course), but it is slow and painful process, that I would like to speedup, because frankly the coverage reports are depressing.

It seems such tools exists for java, c#.